# LINQ PredicateBuilder multiple OR starting with PredicateBuilder.True<>

Tags: c#, linq, filter, where-clause, predicatebuilder

I have an entity like this:

```
public class Product()
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to implement a search for keywords on the `Name` property so that they're OR'ed. In other words, a search for:

> spoon knife fork

will search for *spoon* **or** *knife* **or** *fork* in the `Name` property. I introduced a new method for `PredicateBuilder` on `Product` that looks like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<Product, bool>> ContainsKeywords(params string[] keywords)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Product>();

    foreach (var keyword in keywords)
    {
        var temp = keyword;
        predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Name.Contains(temp));
    }

    return predicate;
}
```

And I'm using it like this in one of my methods for a web service:

```
var keywords = Request.QueryString["q"].Split(' ');
var products = Repo.GetAll<Product>(); // get all the products from the DB
products = products.Where(Product.ContainsKeywords(keywords));
```

The problem I'm running into is that the user may choose not to do a keyword search, in which case the `keywords` array will be empty. If I start with `PredicateBuilder.True<Product>()`, I get a list of all `Products`, regardless of what keywords I put in. If I start with `PredicateBuilder.False<Product>()`, it works if the user inputs keywords, but if not, then the return list is empty because everything matched `false`.

How do I fix this in order to get my desired behavior, which is to return a list of all `Products` if no keyword was provided, and return a list of only the `Products` that matches the keywords if they were provided? I know I can do a check to see if the keywords array is empty before I do any processing, but if at all possible, I'd like `PredicateBuilder` to handle this case automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var predicate = (keywords.Count() > 0)
    ? PredicateBuilder.False<Product>()
    : PredicateBuilder.True<Product>();
```

Comment: Yeah, that's best, but he specifically asked for a way without checking if the list is empty.

Comment: Well, optimally I'd like to do that. I did `if (!keywords.Any()) return PredicateBuilder.True<Product>()`, but I wanted to see if there were other solutions out there.

Comment: that is optimal, what is the problem checking for empty array?